# Processing Form Events Without Application

Tags: c#, forms, events

I have a windows form without running it in an application.

this is the core function that i have to call within the form... there are some class variables the only really important one is the closingpermission. the user has to press a button to close the window.

Unfortunately i cant get it to update and process events. `this.Update()`, `this.Refresh()` wont do the trick.

```
    internal short ask(String question, String RegExFilter, out String answer)
    {
        this.RegExFilter = RegExFilter;
        this.Text = question;

        this.Show();
        while (!closingpermission)
        {
           //Window needs to process its events and allow the user to interact.
        }
        answer = answerBox.Text;
        this.Close();
        return RetVal;
    }
```

EDIT:

"Application" means the singleton Application - i dont have that.

The loop has to keep the form displayed - i think the soution is something [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) wrote. I need to pump a message loop.

The solution of [Ken2K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870604/ken2k) does not work for me.

Edit #2:

Here is a compileable Example - the update methos refreshes my window but i can not edit the textbox - nevermind about the button or what i will do next with the text. I cant even edit the text.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing; //System.Drawing.dll

namespace StackOverFlowDemo
{
    class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Input input = new Input();
            input.Ask("Something");
        }
    }

    class Input : Form
    {
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

        public Input()
        {
            this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { textbox });
            this.Bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
            this.textbox.Bounds = new Rectangle(10, 10, 480, 200);
        }

        internal void Ask(string question)
        {
            this.Text = question;
            this.Show();
            while (true)
            {
                this.Update();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit #3

I think what i want can not be done. I read up on the Topic and it seems that you need "something" that calls `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m);` all the time. That something seems to be Application. I am unaware of any way to do this in an application that does not have an application. Please disagree with me :)

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean 'without application'?

Comment: Obviously it doesn't work because you don't have an 'application'.  The Application.Run() call is required to keep forms alive, it pumps the message loop.  Or Form.ShowDialog().

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721962/c-sharp-application-run-without-form) and at the accepted answer.

Comment: I looked at it. 1) can not work since i do not get to use the singleton "Application". 2) ... i need to show a Form - i dont understand how this could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first commenters had it rigth from the start.

> Obviously it doesn't work because you don't have an 'application'. The
>   Application.Run() call is required to keep forms alive, it pumps the
>   message loop. Or Form.ShowDialog(). – Hans Passant Mar 9 at 12:34

If you want to use Froms you also have to use application - i you dont want to use application you have to switch to some other framework for visualisation like XNA as an example.

Accept that there is a singleton in your app and use the application.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're trying to pop-up a Form to the user and ask him to enter some text. Don't do an infinite loop, it won't work. `Update` and `Refresh` are pointless too.

You could use a modal form (often preferable for a pop-up that prompts a value to the user) and the `Cancel` property of the [`FormClosingEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private bool preventClose = true;

    public string ResultString
    {
        get
        {
            // Returns the content of a textbox
            return this.textBox1.Text;
        }
    }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Closes only when button1 is clicked
        this.preventClose = false;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = this.preventClose;
    }
}


using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
{
    frm.ShowDialog();

    string res = frm.ResultString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution will be to use `Application.DoEvents();` but I'm a bit confused by your title.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` is a dirty workaround that generally only **hides** problems but *doesn't fix them*. Avoid `DoEvents()` as much as possible, it's often the source of evil bugs.

Comment: I had Application.DoEvents(); in there in a different environment - but i no longer have that global "Application", so i cant call anything on it.